# Creating a Json object variable in JS/REACT

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, local-storage

I'm creating a react App that will periodically fetch Json Objects from an URL and display its content. 
(example of an url i'm using: http://demo0046512.mockable.io/stream/anycontent ).

To increase flexibility to my project I want it to be able to display content when offline as well.

For that reason, when I first fetch for the **urls** in that Json object, I want to store their **content** to be able to acess it later, as the urls won't have any use when i'm offline.

To store the data I'm using [localforage Api](https://localforage.github.io/localForage/) and my Idea was to **create a Json Object** just like the one I fetched, but every `url` would be replaced by it's content (text/image/video itself) and then store it with `localForage` to read from it when **offline**, but I haven't found a way to do that so far.

For instance: {ex1 : "https://video.com"} would be stored as {ex2: videoItself}

Can this be done?

Code for anyone interested (Ctrl + f and type " /*!! " for the problem)

https://pastebin.com/AagzuGmx

Answer (score -1):

You want to cache the results you get back from the URL. Might these values ever change? If so, you probably want to keep the  URLs; and the results you fetch from them. Something so if `{ex1 : "https://video.com"}` then `{"https://video.com": video}`

Edit:

The fact that you are caching is important here, including that it may change. But I understand what your question is now. You want to store things like videos using localForage. This can be done, but as the docs say, "All types are supported in every storage backend, though storage limits in localStorage make storing many large Blobs impossible." So the example you give, of a video, will only work for small videos. On mobile browsers, 5MB is the limit, and you might not even get that much because of how localStorage works. It only stores strings, so if strings are stored poorly (and they are in some versions of Android's browser), then you might only get 2.5MB. BTW, this limit is per domain, not file.

One more caveat: you have to encode/serialize these files before storing them. Will they just be videos? Also images? Media with metadata? Entire pages with media? Because the way you encode them might depend on that. If it's just one media type, you can encode it like the final `setItem` example from the docs. Then create a URI like the example does, which can be the `src` of an `<img>` or `<video>` tag.

Comment: Changing or not isn't important here. The main purpose here is to store the content of what I fetched at the time. (if it ever changes, the storage will be overwritten but that's not part of this issue)

Comment: Use IndexedDB instead, it is better for big data and complex operations.

Comment: OP said he was using localForage (which wraps IndexedDB, with a localStorage-like API)